# iOS Safari shows "Error" for <audio> element; but same html works on Mac Safari

Tags: ios, safari, mobile-safari, html5-audio

This html works on all browsers/devices except Safari/iOS:

```
<audio controls="" type="audio/mp4" src="/audio/Quercus%20robur.m4a"></audio>
```

The controls are shown, except it says Error instead of a play control:

[image: Screenshot of problem]

It even works on Chrome/iOS as well as Safari/Mac! I'd like it to work on Safari as I have PWA'd my app.

What can I do?

Comment: I have to same issue, did you resolve this?

Comment: 'Fraid not; had forgotten about it. will check again

Comment: Okay, thnx cause I have the same issue but cannot resolve it.